# Getting back to the previous page with particluar bootstrap tab opened

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

hi I'm currently working on a cordova project. We use cordova and bootstrap mainly.

I'm having two bootstrap tabs.

```
   <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home"></a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1"></a></li>                        
   </ul> 

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="home" class="tab-pane active fade in">         
        </div>
        <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
            <a href="./add_medication.html">add</a>
        </div>  

    </div>
```

Now in my **menu1** tab i'm having this link to *add_medication.html*. In that i'm having a back button which trigger **goBack()** as below

```
   function goBack() {
         activaTab('menu1');
         window.history.go(-1);
         alert("in history");
   }  

   function activaTab(tab){
         alert("in active");
         $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
         alert("I did it");
   }
```

What I need is to return to the previous page with my **menu1** tab opened. All the three alerts are triggered and I'm going back to the previous page. But my activate tab is **home** tab. How to rectify this???

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: can you send jsfiddle link?

Comment: @ishimdar-ahamad No jsfiddle link

Comment: I tried to copy your code but it doesn't work as you are saying. Please you provide us jsfiddle . So that we can fix it.